# Rails -- is IRB necessary?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, irb

I am following Michael Hartl's RoR toturial and there are multiple places where he uses IRB, often to add users to the database.  When I use `rails console` to open IRB and then create a User in the database everything works fine, but if I try to do the same thing by running the same line of code from a file like `test.rb` in the directory of my application it doesn't work b/c it says it can't find the User model.  Is there any way I can run these lines of code (i.e. for putting a user into a database) from a .rb file rather than from the IRB?

Comment: You need to load environment..

Comment: how do I do that?  IRB does it automatically for me, but what syntax do I use if I'm not using IRB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a separate script look into `rails runner`. It loads the Rails backend so you have access to all the models and exists for this purpose.

From the "[Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#runner)":

> runner runs Ruby code in the context of Rails non-interactively. For instance:
>
> $ rails runner "Model.long_running_method"

Answer (score 0):

If you're just using `test.rb` as a convenience to save and re-run console commands, you could do this:

```
rails console < test.rb
```

Or, as a bit of a hack, put this at the top of your `test.rb`:

```
require 'config/environment'
```

And invoke it from the app's root directory like this:

```
ruby -I . test.rb
```

Comment: for that approach it says "Switch to inspect mode." and then exits.

Comment: `rails console < test.rb`, in my case, reports that it's switching to inspect mode and then executes the commands as if I'd typed them. But I like the `rails runner` answer better.

Answer (score 0):

Placing a ruby file in the folder of your app doesn't automatically load up your Rails app. You need to explicitly load the `config/environment.rb` file to load the Rails app.

If your test.rb is in the root of your app, you can do something like

```
require File.expand_path("../config/environment", __FILE__)
# Access your models here
```